# Adding windowing function to linked query from SQL to Oracle causes error

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I have a working SQL Server 2008 query that contains the following. EMR_LIVE is a linked server against OraOLEDB.Oracle, and the back end is Oracle 11g 11.2.0.2.0.

```
left join OpenQuery(EMR_LIVE
    , 'select Person.externalId
            , to_char(ml.convert_id_to_date(Document.clinicalDate), ''yyyymmdd'') as clDate
--          , row_number() over (partition by Orders.sdId order by Orders.orderId) as OrdOrder
            , Orders.code as orderCode
        from ml.Orders
            join ml.Document on Orders.sdId = Document.sdId
            join ml.Person on Orders.pId = Person.pId
        where Person.pId in (
            select Obs.pId
                from ml.Obs
                    join ml.ObsHead on Obs.hdId = ObsHead.hdId
                where ObsHead.name = ''SCHOOLREGDTE''
                    and Obs.xId = 1.e+035
                    and Obs.change = 2
            )
    ') SchoolOrders on pp.PatientId = SchoolOrders.ExternalId
       and convert(nvarchar(12), pv.Visit, 112) = SchoolOrders.clDate
```

However, if I uncomment the row_number line, I get the message 'An error occurred while preparing the query "'...'" for execution against OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "EMR_LIVE".'

When I omitted the ORDER BY clause, it gave me an error telling me I needed to add it, but after I did, it just threw up its hands in disgust and said "go away kid, you're bothering me". If I run the linked query directly against the server in Oracle SQL Developer (with quotes fixed, natch), it works just fine.

Any thoughts on what I'm missing here? Thanks.

Comment: The `order by` clause is required in Oracle's implementation of row_number (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm).  Are your production & developer Oracle instances the same version?  Could be production is older & doesn't have support for that function.

Comment: I've only tested this against production. The problem isn't order by, I just mentioned that to point out the difference in the error messages. Without the order by, it was able to parse the query and figure out it needed that -- with it, it was at a complete loss.